# How to execute a powershell command on the domain controller

Tags: c#, windows, powershell

I have a collection of powershell scripts that need to be executed on the domain controller.

Power shell scripts look like:

```
Remove-AddressBookPolicy -Identity "$KN" -confirm:$false
get-globaladdresslist | where {$_.Name -like "$KN*"} | Remove-GlobalAddressList -confirm:$false
....
```

Now I already have a script that creates a runspace and powershell that run on the local computer and can probably recycle this code (too large for this post) to run on the domain controller instead. I do not know what computer will end up being the local domain controller.

So my question is this: 
How do I execute a powershell script from C# on the domain controller.

Comment: Why not specify the domain controller with -DomainController parameter?

Comment: That could work if I knew an easy way to obtain it and then add that as a parameter (will this be easier to do at the creation of the runspace or within the powershell itself)?

Comment: You can get a list of all the DomainControllers by running Get-DomainController | Select Name, DnsHostName

Comment: What specifically is the question?

Comment: @skukx I would use `Get-ADDomainController -Filter * | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name`. You can go even further with the filter to make sure all of the domain controllers you find are writable.

Comment: So that gets the domain controller but how would I then make the powershell command execute on the domain controller?